# Error while trying to use str.search to find the character "+"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to search for the character "+" inside a string and I'm getting this error:

`error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+/: Nothing to repeat`

This is a sample code to emulate the error I'm experiencing:

```js
var chars1 = 'ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVXZYWK +~!@#$%^&*()';
var char = '+';
var pos = -1;
pos = chars1.search(char);
console.log(pos);
```

How can I search for these kinds of characters in a string?

Comment: Double slash needed `\\+`, result `27`

Comment: Thank you guys, I tried to escape it using only one slash, and then the slash was causing the same issue. :x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only want to search for text, you can use [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), which obviates the need to escape regular expression metacharacters.

```js
var chars1 = 'ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVXZYWK +~!@#$%^&*()';
var char = '+';
var pos = -1;
pos = chars1.indexOf(char);
console.log(pos);
```

Comment: Wow! this is even better! completely bypasses the issue without having to escape special characters! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

`+` is a special character so you need to escape it. Give this a go:

```
var chars1 = 'ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVXZYWK +~!@#$%^&*()';
var char = '\\+'; //Yes double \ needed to escape for the search
var pos = -1;
pos = chars1.search(char);
console.log(pos);
```

For more info check out: https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. I was trying to escape it using only one slash and it was causing the same issue. :x